# Laravel 5 registering a controller to map all methods

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel 5 coming from CodeIgniter background. I have habit to not play with routes.php. CodeIgniter automatically maps methods like  `controllerName/MethodName`.  But in Laravel 5 I am trying to do same by registering a controlller by writing this at top of `app/http/sroutes.php`:

```
Route::controllers([        
    'admin/user' => 'Admin\AdminUserController',
]);
```

When I run `php artisan route:list` it show that controller is registered. But when I see URL `/public/admin/user/addRole` it show addRole method not exist while I have created a method in AdminUserController.

Admin/AdminUserController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class AdminUserController extends Controller {
    public function getaddRole(){
        echo "adding Roles";
    }
}
```

Routes.php

```
 Route::controllers([       
        'admin/user' => 'Admin\AdminUserController',
    ]);
```

Comment: please can you display code for AdminUserController

Comment: @Digitlimit please check my code. I have edited

Comment: /public/admin/user/add-role .If your controller action contains multiple words, you may access the action using "dash" syntax in the URI

Comment: OMG seriously Laravel 5 has very very less info in docs. @Digitlimit ya this solved my problem and i got new idea. The only thing was how i write method name.  I changed my method to getAddRole and now i can access in url as  /add-role.  cool.  also as lucasgeiter suggested anyAddRole now i can access any call (G/P/P/D) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class AdminUserController extends Controller {
    public function getAddRole(){
        echo "adding Roles";
    }
}
```

NB: Notice getAddRole() not getaddRole(), use camelCase

If your controller action contains multiple words, you may access the action using "dash" syntax in the URI like this:

public/admin/user/add-role

Comment: I am surprised why it is not in Doc? BTW thanks man for such quick solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell because I don't see your controller code but I assume you missed adding a HTTP verb to the method name. Like:

```
public function getAddRole(){
    // ...
}
```

If you want the method to match any request method, use `any`:

```
public function anyAddRole(){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference but try it with a capital A

Comment: hey lucas i Got answer :)  it was just name convention. check above comment